# Login Page and then Navigate to another View (UIViewController)

Tags: ios5, authentication, navigation, storyboard

I am using iOS5 stoyboards. I want to create a login screen for the Application and navigate to another View Controller in case username and password provided are correct. Currently I am taking hard coded strings for Username and Password.

How can I navigate to another View Controller from the Login Screen?

Any help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would present the login screen as a modal view on top of you root view controller.

Comment: okay, but how do I navigate from the modal view controller to specific view controller based on the login? Any example??

Comment: This depends on to structure of you app.

Comment: Was able to fix it using prepareForSegue